# How to integrate Pygame and PyQt4?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pygame, ubuntu-14.04

I'm using python 2.7 and Ubuntu 14.04.

I'm trying to do [this](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.init) in order to have my pygame window inside my GUI

> **On some platforms it is possible to embed the pygame display into an already existing window. To do this, the environment variable SDL_WINDOWID must be set to a string containing the window id or handle. The environment variable is checked when the pygame display is initialized**

So this is what I did:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import os
import subprocess
import sys

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
    MainWindow.setFixedSize(800, 600)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    self.iniMap()

def iniMap(self):
    command = "xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW"
    output = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", command], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    activeWindowID = str(output.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8").strip().split()[-1])
    os.environ['SDL_WINDOWID'] = activeWindowID
    import pygame
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((565, 437), pygame.NOFRAME)

class frmMain(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(frmMain, self).__init__(parent, flags=QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = frmMain()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But it doesn't work. It only shows my PyQt window. I don't know whether I'm doing something wrong or pygame just cannot be integrated with PyQt

What should I do to get my pygame window embedded in `frmMain`?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not render all to an off-screen surface, then copy this surface pixels to the PyQt4 window.  Is the performance not good enough?

Comment: Is there a way to copy the surface pixels to PyQt4 window? I guess I can try but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a sample solution as per the comment above:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import pygame
import sys

class ImageWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,surface,parent=None):
        super(ImageWidget,self).__init__(parent)
        w=surface.get_width()
        h=surface.get_height()
        self.data=surface.get_buffer().raw
        self.image=QtGui.QImage(self.data,w,h,QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB32)

    def paintEvent(self,event):
        qp=QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.drawImage(0,0,self.image)
        qp.end()


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,surface,parent=None):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setCentralWidget(ImageWidget(surface))



pygame.init()
s=pygame.Surface((640,480))
s.fill((64,128,192,224))
pygame.draw.circle(s,(255,255,255,255),(100,100),50)

app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
w=MainWindow(s)
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: I'm going to try if this works, thanks! But is there a way to embed the whole window?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but if you want a full screen application, then as long as you can create a PyQt4 borderless window on the entire screen, it should be doable.

Comment: Actually your example was what I was looking for :) Thanks!

Comment: Is there an efficient way I could use this code but so that it continuously updates the pygame image? I tried the "timerEvent" function along with a Qt timer, but it appears as though the Pygame image doesn't actually update or change until I resize the Qt UI. Why is this? How can I fix it?

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out. It's as simple as "self.update()" when the timer event function goes off.

Answer (score 2):

Not enough reputation to comment on [Photon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1648011/photon)'s answer, but I just wanted to note that with PyQt6, the QImage formats are now invoked like this:

```
QtGui.QImage.Format.Format_RGB32
```

Credit to [F.R.D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7177722/f-r-d) for pointing this out in another answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69572591/11434361)