# PyGame Refresh in PyQt?

Tags: python, user-interface, pygame, pyqt5

I saw a similar topic which seemed to be exactly what I wanted ([How to integrate Pygame and PyQt4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280057/how-to-integrate-pygame-and-pyqt4)). However, after adding a menu bar and a few other items I realized I could not refresh the pygame display. I think this is because the way they have it is it is only a pygame surface and not a pygame display so doing pygame.display.update()/flip() does not work. I was wondering if there was a way to do this?

The only think I can think of is instead of putting pygame in PyQT put PyQT inside pygame, but I am not really sure how to do this.

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QDesktopWidget, QApplication, QMainWindow, QStatusBar
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *
#get GUi settings
windowWidth = 500
windowHeight = 500
#colors
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
black = (0,0,0)
yellow = (240,240,0)
class ImageWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,surface,parent=None):
        super(ImageWidget,self).__init__(parent)
        w=surface.get_width()
        h=surface.get_height()
        self.data=surface.get_buffer().raw
        self.image=QtGui.QImage(self.data,w,h,QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB32)
    def paintEvent(self,event):
        qp=QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.drawImage(0,0,self.image)
        qp.end()
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    global windowWidth
    global windowHeight
    def __init__(self,surface,parent=None):
        global windowWidth
        global windowHeight
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(500, 100, windowWidth, windowHeight)
        print(windowWidth)
        self.move(QApplication.desktop().screen().rect().center() - self.rect().center())
        self.setCentralWidget(ImageWidget(surface))
        self.showMaximized()
        #self.showFullScreen()
        #screen_resolution = app.desktop().screenGeometry()
        #windowWidth, windowHeight = screen_resolution.width(), screen_resolution.height()
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight)
        self.createUI()
    def createUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Test game')
        #Menubar
        #First item
        menu = self.menuBar().addMenu('Menu')
        menuSettings = menu.addAction('Settings')
        #action.triggered.connect(self.changeFilePath)
        menuNewGame = menu.addAction('New Game')
        menuSaveGame = menu.addAction('Save Game')
        menuLoadGame = menu.addAction('Load Game')
        # Statusbar
        #self.statusBar().showMessage("test",5000)
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Game Loaded")
def resizePyGame():
    gameScreen.fill(green)
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.draw.circle(gameScreen, (255, 0, 255, 255), (100, 100), 50)
    mainWindow.setGeometry(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight)
    # pygame.display.set_mode((640,480), FULLSCREEN)
pygame.init()
#gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400),0,32)
gameScreen =pygame.Surface((200,100))
gameScreen.fill(red)
pygame.draw.circle(gameScreen,(255,255,255,255),(100,100),50)
app=QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWindow=MainWindow(gameScreen)
infoObject = pygame.display.Info()
windowWidth = infoObject.current_w
windowHeight = infoObject.current_h
#pygame.display.set_mode((50,100), FULLSCREEN)
resizePyGame()
mainWindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the `QImage` that is stored in the `image` attribute of `ImageWidget`; maybe add an `update` method like this:

```
def update(self, surface)
    self.data=surface.get_buffer().raw
    self.image=QtGui.QImage(self.data,w,h,QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB32)
```

(or store the surface in an attribute)

Answer (score 0):

An example from the previous answers:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPainter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton
import pygame
import sys

class ImageWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,surface,parent=None):
        super(ImageWidget,self).__init__(parent)
        self.w=surface.get_width()
        self.h=surface.get_height()
        self.data=surface.get_buffer().raw
        self.image=QImage(self.data,self.w,self.h,QImage.Format_RGB32)
    #sloth
    def update(self, surface):
        self.data = surface.get_buffer().raw
        self.image = QImage(self.data, self.w, self.h, QImage.Format_RGB32)


    def paintEvent(self,event):
        qp=QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.drawImage(0,0,self.image)
        qp.end()

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,surface,parent=None):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedWidth(900)
        self.setFixedHeight(900)
        self.surface=surface
        self.img=ImageWidget(self.surface)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.img)

        self.button = QPushButton('PyQt5 button', self)
        self.button.setToolTip('This is an example button')
        self.button.move(800, 70)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.hagoAlgo)
        #self.timer = QTimer()
        #self.timer.timeout.connect(self.hagoAlgo)
        #self.startTimer()

        self.mu=0

    def upd(self):
        s = pygame.Surface((640, 480))
        s.fill((64, 128, 192, 224))
        pygame.draw.circle(s, (55, 11, 55, 111), (self.mu, self.mu), 50)
        self.img.update(s)
        #self.img = ImageWidget(self.surface)


    def hagoAlgo(self):
        self.mu += 1
        print(self.mu)
        self.upd()
        self.update()
     


    def startTimer(self):
        self.timer.start(1000)
    def endTimer(self):
        self.timer.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()

    s = pygame.Surface((640, 480))
    s.fill((64, 128, 192, 224))
    pygame.draw.circle(s, (255, 255, 255, 255), (100, 100), 50)

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow(s)
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```